# How to use swagger with Functional Web Framework

Tags: java, spring, web, functional-programming, swagger

I try to find a way to use swagger with Spring 5 Functional Web Framework with Java.
Is there a way to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, as of now, there is no way of using swagger in a functional web framework, check here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3265